# Unable to open databse file sql lite android

Tags: android, database, file, sqlite

I'm trying to to create a database and insert some data into it but this doesn't seem to be working. Can anybody tell me what's wrong in my implementation? Here is my code for the database. Thank you.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
 db.openOrCreateDatabase("order", null);
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY     AUTOINCREMENT, Name VARCHAR, Price INTEGER)");
          db.execSQL("INSERT INTO order (Name, Price) VALUES ('Paneer Tikka', '100')");
```

Comment: What is an error you faced please print Logs or trace

Comment: 03-02 22:14:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(463): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file

Comment: apparently SQLite doesn't allow database name to be "order". May be it is reserved by SQLite.

Comment: I think you cannot create files in root (/) directory (or whatever current folder is). Use Environment class to get "right" folders. Where is LogCat?

Comment: I've fixed the error the problem was with the tablename.Have a look at my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteDatabase db = null;

db.openOrCreateDatabase.. will result in NullPointerException. You need to assign SQLLiteDatabase instance to db and then call openOrCreateDatabase on db.

Another issue is, 100 is integer, don't need in single quotes.

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO order (Name, Price) VALUES ('Paneer Tikka', 100)");
```

Comment: there are couple of issues with your code, you need to fix one by one. See my answer. see this link on how to SQLLiteDatabase instance http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: I'm using these statements in my onCreate method does that make any difference?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but you may give a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really nice tutorial supplied by google. It take you through how to do the basics with the SQLite database.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

I would suggest going through that.

In that tutorial is suggests using a SQLHelper inner class something like this

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CELEBS);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CHECKINS);
    Log.i("dbCreate", "must have worked");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("dbCreate", e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS celebs");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS checkins");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Then to get a new database you can call

```
mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: I dont want to extend the SQLiteOpenHelper class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about SQLiteOpenHelper. Ask Google for some tutorials.

Comment: I have seen codes that dont extend this class yet can create a database.

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly Sqlite has much better performance "in transation" on inserts without transaction. I particularly, massive use transaction processes, or failure comes randomly at some point.